# Check if there is any path between two nodes in an undirected graph without going through a particular node

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I investigated all the possible paths between those two nodes by applying bfs/dfs. Though i'm getting correct result but its taking too much time.
what should I do ?

Here's my java code of BFS implementation-

Here s = source vertex or first vertex;

d = destination or second vertex;

b = that particular point to avoid.

```
boolean BFS(int s, int d, int b)
{

    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];

    LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    visited[s]=true;
    queue.add(s);
    if(s==b)
        return false;
    upper:
    while (queue.size() != 0)
    {
        s = queue.poll();
        if(s==b)
            continue upper;
        if(s==d)
            return true;
        Iterator<Integer> i = adj[s].listIterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            int n = i.next();
            if (!visited[n])
            {
                visited[n] = true;
                queue.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It returns true if there is such path, false if there is no such path.

Comment: coudl you add some of the code you have and maybe an execution sample with execution times?

Comment: Yeah sure, I edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: It could be a simple case of Iteraor class taking up resources, you create a new on each iteration of first while and then have another while, have you tried threading to maybe reduce tasksize for each iterator?

Comment: Codechef June16 challenge ? The challenge is not yet over.